# List all site collections in Home Page

Tags: 2016, site, collection

Considering I have these site collections for my web application 
https://server:12345/projects/project1
https://server:12345/projects/project2
https://server:12345/projects/project3

Is there a way that I could list all projects in my home page(https://server:12345/)

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: What are you struggling with? It seems your already on the right path?

Comment: image is not mine. got it on google

Comment: Ah Ok makes sense, please view my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Search Results Webpart (Which is what is shown in you screenshot).

When you edit the Webpart you can open the "Build Your Query" window, and set it to "Only return sites".

You can also configure the sort order / and number of results to display on each page.

[image]

Comment: doesn't show. do i need to configure something on the child site collections?

Comment: what doesn't show ? The webpart or the sites?

Comment: The list of sites weren't shown

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to Sharepoint 2016 you can try building a visual web part with a logic to show all the site collection in the web application and then deploy it to your farm

you can check the below link for create visual webpart

[Create Visual webpart in Sharepoint 2013/2016](https://www.sharepointsky.com/sharepoint-2016-visual-web-part-using-visual-studio/)